# send link in text message in iPhone

Tags: ios, sms

I am developing an app in which the requirement is to send a link in text message.I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` if iPhone and tried HTML string but it doesn't work. I am using  the code:

```
-(IBAction)sendToSMS:(id)sender
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    //  NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:phoneNumber,nil];
    //  [controller setRecipients:[arr objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSLog(@"received:- %@",controller.recipients);
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.body =@"<html><body><font color=#FFFFFF>Hello,<br><a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">click</a>---here to go to Yahoo!</font></body></html>";


    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {   
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SMS does not support HTML or URLs, just plain text.

All you can do is just add the URL to message and then it's up to the Message app to recognize the URL and allow the user to click on it.

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like this:

`controller.body =@"Hello, here is a link to Yahoo!\nhttp://www.yahoo.com";`

If the receiving phone supports URLs (most of them these days) it'll automatically make it actionable (touchable, clickable, selectable or whatever)

Comment: As @rckoenes correctly states SMS does not support HTML, it is just plain text. Why do you not want to show the URL?